# Facing issue while creating Hive external table with s3 location

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, ambari

I am trying to create external table with s3 location.

```
create external table trial
(
  Country string,
  Date1 string,
  Brand string)
  location 's3n://poc/xyzpoc.csv' 
 )
```

I have already mentioned the Access and Secret Access key in Custom hdfs-site and Custom hive-site but still I am getting access key error.

Below properties I have set

```
fs.s3a.access.key,
fs.s3a.secret.key
```

Error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3n URL, or by setting the fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively). [ERROR_STATUS]

Comment: Have you tried doing it the way the error tells you it needs to be done? `location 's3n://AKIAEXAMPLEKEY:ExampleSecretzzz@poc/xyzpoc.csv'`

Answer (score 1):

Use a url with s3a in it instead, like "s3a://poc/xyzpoc.csv". It's the successor S3 client, and is configured slightly differently (better, as it supports various other mechanisms)